# iCloud Core Data Model Schema Migration

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, icloud

Acording to [Apple's Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW9), The lightweight migration for core data connected with iCloud can be performed automatically. And [another documents from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/vmCloud/vmCloud.html) says that:

> If you migrate a persistent store configured with a
>   NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey option to a new model
>   version, the store’s history of changes originating from the current
>   device will also be migrated and then merged with any other devices
>   configured with that new model version. Any changes from stores using
>   the new version are also merged in.
>
> Existing changes can not, however,
>   be migrated to a new model version if the migration is performed using
>   a custom mapping model.

I could change my app to use iCloud, and I could migrate(manual) local database into ubiquity one successfully. So first core data with iCloud doesn't show any problems.

However, when I added new model version,
The migrated store contains nothing. It is supposed to be contains migrated content that is created with older version of model.
`the store’s history of changes` seems to be ignored for some reason.

As a result, Testers who installed new version of the app loses content which created with earlier version. There were no logs or errors.

When I tried same initializing process to store without `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` option(local store), everything were fine. All content are migrated and contained by new store correctly.

And the second documents says:

> Existing changes can not, however,
>   be migrated to a new model version if the migration is performed using
>   a custom mapping model.

I think that My needs can be match this case.
I have also custom mapping models.
But I don't know the place to trigger.

My store options are very typical, not so special:

```
{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey = "moment-cloud";
    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey = Logs;
}
```

Store URL is created as:

```
NSURL* docURL = [fileManager URLsForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory inDomains: NSUserDomainMask].firstObject;
return [docURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: kFileNameDatabaseForUbiquitous];
```

Comment: It's not clear if you're using a custom mapping model or not.

Comment: @laucel Unfortunately, This problem is not reproducible with concrete state. But it still happens without any strong clues on AppStore(or test flight). When user updates the app, the peer id seems to be changed(not changed with Xcode debugging), it should not be changed after update, as a result, old peer is not migrated(because it is treated as different device), just creates new empty store. Apple's technical support was not helpful. I just removed iCloud+Core data features on my Product. And I will never use iCloud+coredata again.

Comment: @jeeeyul this is exactly my worst fear, but I can't remove iCloud+Core Data features, thanks for your feedback